# Abrir Pop up con varios botones

Tags: javascript, html, popup

No logro que varios botones abran un único popup. Así es como lo hice:

```
<div class="popup">
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <p>Evita sanciones por el incumplimiento de la ley.
             Tu tranquilidad empieza con una tributación sana.</p>
          <img src="assets/images/flechablanca.png" alt="Diagnostico">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h2>Solicita hoy tu diagnóstico <strong>gratis</strong></h2>
          <form action="/action_page.php">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailsqyhh">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwdsjkn">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="aa" class="form-control" id="pwdfff">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Este botón funciona bien:

```
<button type="button" id="myBtn" class="btn btn-default"> 
<strong>SOLICITAR</strong></button>
```

pero no los siguientes botones:

```
<button type="button" id="myBtn" class="btn btn-default">Conoce ayudamos</button>

<button type="button" id="myBtn" class="btn btn-default">SOLICITAR AHORA</button>
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un error grave con los IDs de los botones.

**Un ID en un elemento HTML debe ser único, dentro del documento HTML.**

En tus botones veo que has repetido el mismo ID: *myBtn*. Tu javascript sólo va a reconocer el primer elemento con esa ID.

Lo que puedes hacer es asignar diferentes IDs a cada botón, por ejemplo: *myBtn1*, *myBtn2* y *myBtn3*.

Y asociar el evento *onclick* a cada uno de ellos como lo tienes en tu código, sólo que en este caso puede que sea preferible no abrir el popup en una función anónima, sino en una "normal" que invoques al pulsar cada botón.

Un saludo.

Comment: los coloque pero ahora solo me lee el ultimo boton

Comment: ya lo solucione es que no me fije el nombre de las variables, gracias bro